# Keep track of the user in my website

Tags: javascript, php, html, authentication

I Know that this might be a very silly question to ask, but please keep in mind that this is my first project in web development and programming 
I'm designing a CV maker website 
I've done this interface using the help of a predefined template:
[image] and once the user is logged in, I'm redirecting is to another page myResume.php where he has to enter his info and so, here is the interface : 
[image]. Now comes my question: How I'm supposed to track the user after he logs in? I mean how can I make sure that no one sees this page unless he logged in first ? 
Using my design, anyone can see the myResume page by using the specific URL, example : http://www.example.com/myResume.php 
 Reformulation, Is it possible to restrict the redirection to myResume.php to only from the login.php file ? 
Thank you

Comment: http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/

Comment: Have you tried doing a search with the keywords 'php', 'login', 'authentication' or a combination of these? I'm sure Google and Stack Overflow will have plenty of results.

Comment: You need a user (login) system, and seeing that you asked this question, maybe it is a good thing to use an allready made system. Security is hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did this like 2 days ago for a site i'm creating.

So what you want to do is set up session variables and check to see if they are there or not. I assume you have the login functionallity working, Where it checks the database to see if the user name and password match. If it does, you send them to the `myResume.php`.

The next step under `login.php` would be to set up a `$_SESSION['user_id']` variable in php. This matches the session of a user to a serverside session. This variable is help on the server side with an access key stored in local cookies to match the session to the user. [What is a Session?](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

The next thing you will want to do is add an if and header to every file on your site that should only be allowed access to logged in users.

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

If you want to log out you do something like this. You send them to a logout.php and in the logout.php file you simple have this statement.

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location: login.php');
```

you have to allways start your session on each page before you can, use, set, destroy session variables.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is the session:
[PHP manual on sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

It lets you store information that your scripts can access as your user moves from page to page.

Have a look at [tiztag tutorial on sessions](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php)
or [a sitepoint tutorial on sessions](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions/)

hth

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so now using session, is the check for session_is_registered(username) enough? If it is not registered I redirect the user to the login page? Thank again

Comment: No, the session is a special place to store data. If you just check to see if it's there then that won't tell you what's actually in it.  We access it as an associative array, so first (if you're working in php) you need to start it, then you need to store the user details in it. Once they're there you can set variables like (again in php) $_SESSION['isValidUser'] (for example) that every other page can read and see if they should let the user have access or not.  There are considerations of size (most servers only let you have a maximum of 4,000 characters total) but first things first.

Answer (score 1):

Use session cookies.  Here are a few places to look... http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php,  http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/